# Shortcut ‘Ctrl-+’ not working in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, angular, codemirror

Why shortcut ‘Ctrl-+’ not working in CodeMirror ?

```
import { CodemirrorComponent } from 'ng2-codemirror';
...
@ViewChild('novelEditor') private novelEditor: CodemirrorComponent;
...
const cm = this.novelEditor.instance;
const codeMirrorHotKeyMap = this.editorService.getCodeMirrorHotKeyMap(this.novelEditor);
cm.addKeyMap(codeMirrorHotKeyMap, false);
...
getCodeMirrorHotKeyMap(codeMirror: CodemirrorComponent) {
  return {
     'Ctrl-+': () => console.log('ctrl +'), // not working
     'Ctrl--': () => console.log('ctrl -')
  }
}
```

‘Ctrl–’, ‘Ctrl-*’, ‘Ctrl-/’,‘Ctrl-.’,‘Ctrl-0’ - working all, but only ‘Ctrl-+’ not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at their [docs](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#keymaps):

> Alternatively, a character can be specified directly by surrounding it
>   in single quotes, for example '$' or 'q'. Due to limitations in the
>   way browsers fire key events, **these may not be prefixed with
>   modifiers.**

It says you can't combine it with modifiers. Only named keys under `CodeMirror.keyNames` can be used with modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Wrote instead 'Ctrl-+' 'Ctrl-=' and working

```
return {
     'Ctrl-=': () => console.log('ctrl +'), // now working
     'Ctrl--': () => console.log('ctrl -')
  }
```